# SQL Server 2012 : finding the closest date, of muliple columns & rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, compare, datediff, row-number

I'm struggling with finding the best way to ge the closest value from multiple columns and rows. In the code below I only get the `SEQ` number from the `StartDate`, but I also need to know if the `EndDate` of row 1 is closer than start date compared to `@ValidationTime`.

For example, if `@Validationtime` is 10:10, row 1 is the closest value, but 10:20 is closer to row 2.

In the end, I will only handle the "closest slot" (1 row).

I hope I explained it in a not too messy way. :)

```
DECLARE @ValidationTime as datetime

SET @ValidationTime = '2017-08-29 10:10:00.000'
--SET @ValidationTime = '2017-08-29 10:20:00.000'

DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime);

INSERT INTO @table 
VALUES (1, '2017-08-29 08:00:00.000', '2017-08-29 10:00:00.000'),    
       (1, '2017-08-29 10:30:00.000', '2017-08-29 21:00:00.000'),    
       (1, '2017-08-30 08:00:00.000', '2017-08-30 10:00:00.000'),
       (1, '2017-08-30 19:00:00.000', '2017-08-30 21:00:00.000');

SELECT 
    ID, StartDate, EndDate, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDate, @ValidationTime))) AS SEQ
FROM 
    @table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CASE . . WHEN to check which is nearer

```
SELECT  ID, 
    StartDate, 
    EndDate, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Partition by  ID
                Order by CASE   WHEN ABS(DateDiff(MINUTE,StartDate,@ValidationTime)) < ABS(DateDiff(MINUTE,EndDate,@ValidationTime))
                        THEN ABS(DateDiff(MINUTE,StartDate,@ValidationTime))
                        ELSE ABS(DateDiff(MINUTE,EndDate,@ValidationTime))
                        END
              ) AS SEQ
FROM    @table
```

Comment: Yes, of course!  Case! Why didn´t i think of that. Thank you!